# Safari does not display SVG when using flexbox to center it

Tags: css, svg, flexbox, safari

I’ve got an issue with Safari, SVG, and flexbox

The goal is to have a responsive SVG, that keeps the aspect ratio (16:9). Moreover, the SVG should always sit in the vertical and horizontal center of the screen. The following code works well for all browsers except for Safari... I tried different vendor prefixes, but I have no clue why the SVG is not showing up... Any ideas?

You can test the flawed behavior in the code snippet below. Safari will show a blank page. Other browsers will show a 16:9, always centered teal rectangle.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

svg {
  background-color: teal;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
</svg>
```

#### Update

Just some clarification. Depending on the aspect ratio of the viewport, the SVG is either in horizontal center or vertical center. Only when the screen aspect ratio is exactly 16:9 it matches the SVS’s viewBox (see `viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"`), and it would show without any borders (letterboxes). That is my goal, and solution should work in all browsers—no matter how it is done.

[image]

Comment: Instead of max-height try using flex for example `flex: 0 0 100vh;`

Comment: Can repro, one fix is to set the `height` and `width` attributes to `1920` and `1080` and then override it through CSS as `auto`.

Comment: @enxaneta, no. I’m losing horizontal responsiveness and the I get some padding on the sides: https://jsfiddle.net/akdu6qep/

Comment: @Kaiido width and height attributes of the SVG?

Comment: Yes, but it actually only works on Safari-TP, not on current stable... Sorry.

Comment: All good. Nevertheless, I would also like to avoid setting width and height props. I’d rather stick to viewBox to define the boundaries of my SVG.

Comment: I believe @Kaiido meant set the width and height as he suggests. Then override them in CSS by setting them both to `100%`. That's equivalent to not setting them at all.

Comment: I cannot get this to work ... Moreover, if this only works in Safari-TP, it is not a solution :/

Comment: Where did you get the info that it should work in all browsers no matter how it is done?

Comment: I mean rather that a solution should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vanilla CSS example ...

It is done in modern styling technique using CSS functions `min(...)` and `var(...)`. As the styling is done for a fullsize viewscreen the sizings can be calculated based on `aspect-ratio` of the svg/image and actual `vW` and `vH`units. Modern centering is done by using `flexbox` as well.

It should run in all modern browsers.

Please check the example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100vH;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

svg {
  --aspectRatio: 1.7777777;
  width: min(100vW, (100vH * var(--aspectRatio)));
  height: min(100vH, (100vW / var(--aspectRatio)));
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"></svg>
```

Comment: Great work! The vendor prefixes are not even necessary. So, instead of `max-height`—which was problematic for Safari—you give an explicit calculated `width` and `height`, which is fine for Safari… Do you have any insight into why my original code was failing for Safari? Anyway, super glad that there is a CSS solution. I cannot unfortunately undo or split the bounty. Thank you!

Comment: Thx for feedback. And as I pointed out: as it has not been in time Bounty is OK of course! But thx for choosing the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is javascript based solution:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const wByH = 16 / 9;

function computeSVGDimen() {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  const currentRatio = width / height;

  const computedWidth = height * wByH;
  const computedHeight = width * (1 / wByH);

  if (currentRatio < wByH) {
    svg.style.width = `${width}px`;
    svg.style.height = `${computedHeight}px`;
  } else {
    svg.style.width = `${computedWidth}px`;
    svg.style.height = `${height}px`;
  }
}

computeSVGDimen();
window.onresize = computeSVGDimen;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

svg {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! This is indeed a working solution for Safari. Yet, it is a bummer that it requires some JavaScript. I will accept/reward tomorrow if there is no CSS solution. Thank you again for the investigation!

Comment: Even I tried a lot to do it with CSS but the way Safari handles everything is just different from every other browser. I have had a horrible time fixing minute things for Safari. I hope someone comes up with a pure CSS solution, even I would prefer that.

Answer (score -1):

use this in .css file

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {svg {background-color: teal;}}
```

Comment: Could elaborate more on your answer; adding your code seems to make things even worse: https://jsfiddle.net/McTell/vj9mpckx/5/